# How to list similar lines?

Tags: bash, grep, statistics

The delimiters could be: " "; "_"

INPUT:

```
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 111 will expire within the next seven d
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 111 will expire within the next seven d
sadf#sadf this is a sample_text
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 222 will expire within the next seven da
foo - moreeee test
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 222 will expire within the next seven da
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 333 will expire within the next seven day
ldr#ldr_another sample text
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 333 will expire within the next seven day
```

OUTPUT:

```
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 111 will expire within the next seven d
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 111 will expire within the next seven d
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 222 will expire within the next seven da
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 222 will expire within the next seven da
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 333 will expire within the next seven day
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 333 will expire within the next seven day
```

So similar words in the given lines are ex.:

```
The
password
of
user
will
expire
within
the
```

**My question:** are there any methods to only OUTPUT the lines that are similar to an extent? Ex. they match by 8 words
Are there any shell scripts that can detect this?

Comment: Would a solution where you supply a percentage similarity level to find lines that match within that percentage be acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the the text in order, you can try:

```
$ grep 'The.*password.*of.*user.*will.*expire.*within.*the' file 
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 111 will expire within the next seven d
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 111 will expire within the next seven d
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 222 will expire within the next seven da
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 222 will expire within the next seven da
foo#foo_ehh113#The password of user 333 will expire within the next seven day
foo#foo_ehh204#The password of user 333 will expire within the next seven day
```

If you have a file to hold the group of text, called group.txt, you can use:

```
$ grep $(printf "%s.*" $(cat group.txt)) file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it entering the next in commandline, you can give as manny keywords as you like:

```
grep -E "one|two|three" file.txt
```

if source is dmesg do:

```
dmesg | grep -E "one|two|three"
```